# Leaflet control to display scale in native/declared CRS (i.e. degrees)

Tags: leaflet, latitude-longitude, scale

I'd like to have a Leaflet map display the scale of a layer in native coordinates (i.e. degrees in EPSG:4326). From what I have read so far the map control always handles meters; is there a way to change its behavior to show native CRS units?

Comment: Are you saying you want to show a scale bar that tells someone something like "1 inch equals 0.5 degrees"? I can't recall ever seeing a scale bar that uses an angular unit, probably because a) people are not good at knowing how far a degree or fraction of a degree is (myself included) and b) you're map is flat so linear units are appropriate, not angular units.

Comment: Yes, that is almost what I'm looking for. To be precise I'd like to have 1 inch equals 0.5 degrees, and the possibility to re-label degrees to something else. That way I can have a constant scale on the whole map. Using a different projection to obtain the same result is also an option.

Comment: What you're asking for will likely mislead and confuse people. I say that because the size of a degree varies based on where you are on the globe. A degree of longitude at the equator is much larger than a degree of longitude farther North, in Norway for instance.